# Define function 'a -> 'b

Tags: ocaml

i have a task to define two functions, one with type:

```
 ('a-> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b
```

and second one with just

```
'a -> 'b
```

while the first function is composition and i've done that this way:

```
let compose f g arg = f(g(arg))
```

i'm stuck on the second one. could anyone lead me to correct answer? i made this one:

```
let a x = List.hd []
```

but im pretty sure there is much simplier example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first function is not currying, it's function composition. Currying has the type `('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c`.

Your solution for `'a -> 'b` is pretty good. Note that `List.hd []` raises an exception. So another implementation is:

```
let f x = raise Not_found
```

The thing to realize is that no "nice" function can possibly have the given type. Where would it get an actual value of type `'b` to return? It would have to be a value that can have any type at all.

Comment: `let rec f x = f x` :-)

Comment: In case you just want "random" behavior instead of crashing or looping, there is `Obj.magic`...